# Java: Problem comparing String variable with "null" value

Tags: java, string, servlets, null, integer

I'm getting a String value from an HttpServletRequest with the method getParameter with the prupose to parse it to Integer.

This value can be a "null" String if the value is not setted in the front-end but when I try to compare it the result is always false

```
Boolean.toString(request.getParameter("parameter") == "null"));
Boolean.toString(request.getParameter("parameter") == null));
Boolean.toString(request.getParameter("parameter").isEmpty()));
Boolean.toString(request.getParameter("parameter").isBlank()));
```

this outputs

```
false
false
false
false
```

Comment: Strings should be compared using `equals`. For example: `request.getParameter("parameter").equals("null")`

Comment: Make sure that you check if the string is `"null"` *after* you check if it's `null`, though.

Comment: For null safety: `Objects.equals(request.getParameter("parameter"), "null")` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `Boolean.toString(request.getParameter("parameter").equals("null"));`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this was just what was happening. `==` not compares the value equality.